# Auto re-size windows form dynamically according to the control visibility, C#.Net

Tags: c#, windows, forms

While creating a windows form application, initially I am keeping all the controls like Button, TextBox, Label invisible. Once, the user do a proper activity like select correct directory then the next control appears (In general, the user won't be having much freedom but to give a correct directory). I know, there is no sense keeping other control invisible all the time but I want to do it as my learning process.

Now, the question is, how do I make the form change it's size each time a new control appears.

e.g. at start only one TextBox and Browse button are visible. Here the windows form should scaled to the visible controls only. Then once user gives a proper directory path and the program recognizes it, next control like a button and a richTextBox will show up and the form then should change itself dynamically to fit new controls.

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all simple enough, you can alter the visibility of a control with the `Visible` property, and change the size of your form by altering the `Height` and `Width` properties of the form.

If you create a form named **Form1**, add two buttons named **button1** and **button2** and copy and paste the following code, this will demonstrate both resizing the form and changing the visibility of controls.

**button2** gets set to invisible as the form loads, and the width and height get set to 100px each. Whenever **button1** is pressed, the form is resized and **button2** is set to visible:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Visible = false;

            Width = 100;
            Height = 100;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Width = 200;
            Height = 200;
            button2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great super easy. thanks a lot. Sometimes, we just make things more complicated unnecessarily. The way how I did. :-)